# How do I generalize these values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have given below ten pairs of values to be generalized. I have been pondering over it since ages. Please help me with it. I want an equation between *x* and *y* that satisfies the given values. At least, give me clues as to how I can solve the problem. Thanks!!!

*Edit:* For x=1 to 10, these are the only y values possible. For x values above 10, other y values exist. Both x and y are strictly positive integers. The graph of these values is not a continuous line, but a collection of discrete random points only.

*My Trials:* I tried to construct piecewise equations for the values, but since they are discrete values, it didn't work. The graph shows no regularity.

[image: Value pairs to be generalized...]

Comment: We need more information on what kind of form you're expecting. There are an infinite number of possibilities. For example, $x\in\mathbb R, y\in\mathbb R$ is a relation which satisfies your table.

Comment: Sorry for calling it a 'relation'. I want an equation satisfying these values.

Comment: Any simple equation that satisfies all the given values would be helpful. If there are more than one, please do tell me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution which attempts to get a simple equation (which isn't unique, of course)

---

We see that $(\forall x, y)\,\,\,x=y\lor x=3y\lor3x=y$.

Therefore one of the possible solutions is$$(x-y)(x-3y)(3x-y)=0$$

---

In general, given a set $S=\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...,(x_n,y_n)\}$, the equation

$$\prod_{i=1}^n(y_ix-x_iy)=0$$

is satisfied by all points in $S$.

---

If you take the general equation above, finding all points which satisfy it isn't actually too hard. Given the form above, we can conclude

$$(\forall x,y)\,\,\,\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(y_ix-x_iy)=0\iff (\exists i)\,\,\,y_ix-x_iy=0\right)$$

So the solutions to the general equation is the union of all solutions to the individual linear equations $y_ix-x_iy=0$ for all $i$.

This can be seen if you sketch the graph. [Example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nzadbw1yoa) in Desmos.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! If you don't mind, can you tell me how I can find more solutions to this general equation you have provided. I am too far in grappling with the power of that equation...

Comment: @Hariharan Not sure what you mean?

Comment: How do I find more solutions of the general equation? What are the solutions of the equation beyond what is given?

Comment: You mean find more equations? That's a difficult question to answer since there really are an infinite number of equations which satisfy those points. Even $0=0$ works (ie. the whole plane). You can then incorporate functions like $\sin, \log, |.|$ as well as your own arbitrary functions. What I've given above is a relatively simple way to get a simple form of what you're after.

Comment: No, not more equations. For example, for equation y=2x+1, (0,1), (1,3) and (2,5) are all solutions, I want to find solutions(or more value pairs apart from what I've given) satisfying the equation involving the product operator you gave. If possible, can I contact you regarding this in a little more detail...

Comment: I see what you mean - edited in.